# Using angular expression in html onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular to build a table for me dynamically. The Expression `user.User.id` needs to be listed out as an integer in each place that I use it and it works everywhere except inside a html script tag that I am using. There it throws an error in javascript. I'm sure there is a better way to do what I'm doing here, but I'm looking for a quick and simple solution to display the user id so that it can be referenced by the script tag.

Here is the code:

```
 <table class="table" ng-hide="loading" >

        <tr>
            <th>Test Search Code</th>
            <th>Test Current Company</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchText ">
            <!-- THESE REFERENCES WORK FINE -->
            <td>{{user.User.mapped_test_search_code}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Employment[0].name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.User.mapped_first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.User.mapped_email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.User.created}}</td>
            <td><a href="/admin/mapped_users/edit/{{user.User.id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>

            <td>

                <!-- THIS ONE WORKS TOO-->
                <form action="{{'/admin/users/delete/' + user.User.id}}" name="post_{{user.User.id}}" id="post_{{user.User.id}}" style="display:none;" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
                </form>

                <!-- THIS ONE IN THE A TAG, IN THE SCRIPT ATTRIBUTE DOES NOT WORK -->
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block" onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Are you sure?&quot;)) { document[ 'post_' + user.
                User.id ].submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;" original-title="">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Use `ng-click="yourFunction()"`, and `$scope.yourFunction = function() { /* whatever */ }`

Comment: You should use `ng-click` and move the confirmation logic into a function in controller.

Comment: Yeah, your javascript there should not be inline, it should be in a js file... like in your controller.